# Drag marker of map not working

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to make map with dragable marker but now my map is not working. I have attached my code below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "report";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

  $error = false;

    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        echo "if";

        // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $name = strip_tags($name);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

        $address = trim($_POST['address']);
        $address = strip_tags($address);
        $address = htmlspecialchars($address);

        $latitude = trim($_POST['latitude']);
        $latitude = strip_tags($latitude);
        $latitude = htmlspecialchars($latitude);

        $longitude = trim($_POST['longitude']);
        $longitude = strip_tags($longitude);
        $longitude = htmlspecialchars($longitude);

        $category = trim($_POST['category']);
        $category = strip_tags($category);
        $category = htmlspecialchars($category);

        $message = trim($_POST['description']);
        $message = strip_tags($message);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($message);

        // basic name validation
        $nameError = false;
        if (empty($name)) {
            $error = true;
            $nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
        } else if (strlen($name) < 3) {
            $error = true;
            $nameError = "Name must have atleat 3 characters.";
        } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
            $error = true;
            $nameError = "Name must contain alphabets and space.";
        }

        // basic address validation
        if (empty($address)) {
            $error = true;
            $addressError = "Please enter your address.";
        } 

        // basic latitude validation
        if (empty($latitude)) {
            $error = true;
            $latitudeError = "Please enter your latitude.";
        }

        // basic longitude validation
        if (empty($longitude)) {
            $error = true;
            $longitudeError = "Please enter your longitude.";
        }

        // basic category validation
        if (empty($category)) {
            $error = true;
            $categoryError = "Please enter your category.";
        } 

        // basic message validation
        if (empty($message)) {
            $error = true;
            $messageError = "Please enter your description.";
        } else if (strlen($message) < 3) {
            $error = true;
            $messageError = "description must have atleat 3 characters.";
        } 

        // if there's no error, continue to insert
        if( !$error ) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO users ( userName , userAddress , userLat , userLong , userCategory , userMessage) VALUES( '$name', '$address', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$category', '$message')";
           // $query = "INSERT INTO users ( userName ,  userMobile , userEmail , userMessage) VALUES( 'abc', 43, 'sdg@dg.vcvb', 'sf')";
            //$query = "select * from users";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    //              echo "New record created successfully";
                $errTy = "success";
                $errMS = "Successfully submitted";
                                unset($name);
                              //  unset($address);
                            //    unset($latitude);
                            //    unset($longitude);
                                unset($category);
                                unset($message);
            } else {
      //            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                $errType = "danger";
                $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);

        }
        else{
           echo "el";
        }


    }
    else{
        echo "else";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <style>
        #myMap {
           height: 650px;
           width: 480px;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var map;
            var marker;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.268455824834792,85.84099235520011);
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            function initialize(){
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: myLatlng,
                    draggable: true 
                });     

                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatlng }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                            $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                            $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    }
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                            $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                            $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float:left;">
            <h2>Report your problem</h2>
            <?php
            if ( isset($errMSG) ) {

                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-<?php echo ($errTy=="success") ? "success" : $errType; ?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">


                User name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required><br><br>
                <span><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>  

                User address:<br>
                <input id="address"  name="address" type="text" style="width:500px;"/><br><br>
                <!-- <?php echo $addressError; ?> -->

                <input type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
                <!--<?php echo $latitudeError; ?>-->
                <input type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>
                <!--<?php echo $longitudeError; ?> --><br><br>

                User category:<br>
                <select name='category'> <option value='-- Pick a category --'>-- Pick a category --</option> <option value='Abandoned vehicles'>Abandoned vehicles</option> <option value='Bus stops'>Bus stops</option> <option value='Car parking'>Car parking</option> <option value='Dog fouling'>Dog fouling</option> <option value='Flyposting'>Flyposting</option> <option value='Flytipping'>Flytipping</option> <option value='Graffiti'>Graffiti</option> <option value='Parks/landscapes'>Parks/landscapes</option> <option value='Pavements/footpaths'>Pavements/footpaths</option> <option value='Potholes'>Potholes</option> <option value='Public toilets'>Public toilets</option> <option value='Roads/highways'>Roads/highways</option> <option value='Road traffic signs'>Road traffic signs</option> <option value='Rubbish (refuse and recycling)'>Rubbish (refuse and recycling)</option> <option value='Street cleaning'>Street cleaning</option> <option value='Street lighting'>Street lighting</option> <option value='Street nameplates'>Street nameplates</option> <option value='Traffic lights'>Traffic lights</option> <option value='Trees'>Trees</option> <option value='Other'>Other</option></select><br><br>
                <!--<?php echo $categoryError; ?>  -->

                User description:<br>
                <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="description" required cols="25" rows="7"  /></textarea><br><br>
              <!--  <?php echo $messageError; ?>  -->

                <input type="submit" name="submit">

            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="myMap"></div><br/>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be kind and paste code here.

Comment: @Kamal, if your edit with your code, will be easier to help you

Comment: sorry sir, I am new to stackoverflow and  i am facing errors while posting code. If you help me i will be very thankful